# simple css scroller not functioning in Firefox

Tags: css

Got a very simple scroller working in chrome and safari, but not in FF.

checked these forums, but can't figure it out.

here's the codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IwtCb

```
   @-webkit-keyframes bgscroll {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:0 -520px;}
    }
    .ani {
      background: url(http://s14.postimg.org/jjtlfx775/scroller.jpg);
      color:#12gh34;
      text-align:left;
      -webkit-animation:bgscroll 14s infinite linear;
    }

    .container {  
      margin: 40;
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

You have @-webkit-keyframes
You need @-moz-keyframes and @keyframes for those browsers engines. 

Firefox isn't a webkit browser.

Comment: Thanks for the link, was unaware of different browser needs!

Answer (score 0):

adding the code:
-moz-animation:bgscroll 14s infinite linear;
animation:bgscroll 14s infinite linear;
into ani class and check,